# File names in Chef InSpec

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, inspec

In Ruby, `*` is used to represent the name of a file.

For example, `/home/user/*.rb` will return all files ending with `.rb`. I want to do something similar in Chef InSpec.

For example:

```
describe file ('home/user/*') do
  it {should_not exist }
end
```

It should give me all the files inside `/home/user` directory and check that no file exists inside this directory. In other words, I want to check if this directory is empty or not in Chef.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` for globs is mostly a shell feature, and as you might expect the `file` resource doesn't support them. Use a `command` resource instead:

```
describe command('ls /home/user') do
  its(:stdout) { is_expected.to eq "\n" }
end
```

Comment: Also can you tell me about this syntax  `its(:stdout) { is_expected.to eq "\n" }`. Its not chef InSpec and what is resource `is_expected` ?

Comment: That's a mix of syntax from RSpec itself and the `rspec-its` gem. Neither are specific to InSpec. Equivalent to `it { expect(subject.stdout).to eq "\n" }` just with a little less-ish typing and a little more readable as a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach that tests for the existence of the directory, and if it exists it uses Ruby to test for files within it.  It also uses the `expect` syntax, which allows for a custom error message.

```
control 'Test for an empty dir' do
  describe directory('/hey') do
    it 'This directory should exist and be a directory.' do
      expect(subject).to(exist)
      expect(subject).to(be_directory)
    end
  end
  if (File.exist?('/hey'))
    Array(Dir["/hey/*"]).each do |bad_file|
      describe bad_file do
        it 'This file should not be here.' do
          expect(bad_file).to(be_nil)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If there are files present, the resulting error message is informative:

```
  ×  Test for an empty dir: Directory /hey (2 failed)
     ✔  Directory /hey This directory should exist and be a directory.
     ×  /hey/test2.png This file should not be here.
     expected: nil
          got: "/hey/test2.png"
     ×  /hey/test.png This file should not be here.
     expected: nil
          got: "/hey/test.png"
```